WPF - Async SSRS Report generating using WindowsFormsHost
I have helper static method to "automatize" generating SSRS reports
public static WindowsFormsHost CreateSSRSReport(string reportServerUrl, string reportSystemName, string reportPath,
    List<Parameter> parameters, int? idKey = null)
{
    WindowsFormsHost windowsFormsHost = new WindowsFormsHost();
    var reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
    reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
    windowsFormsHost.Child = reportViewer;

    ServerReport serverReport = reportViewer.ServerReport;
    serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(reportServerUrl);
    serverReport.ReportPath = String.Concat("/", reportSystemName, "/", reportPath);

    if(idKey != null)
    {
        var reportParameterInfos = serverReport.GetParameters();
        var reportParameterInfo = reportParameterInfos.FirstOrDefault(p => Equals(p.Name, "IdKey"));
        if (reportParameterInfo != null)
        {
            parameters.Add(new Parameter("IdKey", idKey));
        }
    }

    parameters = parameters ?? new List<Parameter>();
    serverReport.SetParameters(parameters.Select(p => new ReportParameter(p.Name, p.Value.ToString())));
    reportViewer.RefreshReport();

    return windowsFormsHost;
}

I would like to await that operation as the loading time is a bit long and displaying ProgessBar till everything is done and ready would improve user experience.
private async Task GenerateReport()
{
    SetWorkingStatus(true);
    Report = await Task.Run(() => ReportingHelper.CreateSSRSReport(_pluginConfiguration.ReportServerPath,
        _pluginConfiguration.ReportSystemName, SelectedReportDetails.SourceName, null));
    SetWorkingStatus(false);
}

But that resulted in System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.'
The main application Main method has [STAThread] attribute specified. My next idea was to use Dispatcher
SetWorkingStatus(true);
await Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
{
    Report = await Task.Run(() => ReportingHelper.CreateSSRSReport(_pluginConfiguration.ReportServerPath,
        _pluginConfiguration.ReportSystemName, SelectedReportDetails.SourceName, null));
});
SetWorkingStatus(false);

But I keep getting the mentioned exception.
The Exception is thrown at WindowsFormsHost windowsFormsHost = new WindowsFormsHost(); line in the helper method.

By Task.Run, the CreateSSRSReport executes in a background thread, which by default does not have ApartmentState.STA. Even if you would accomplish to set that state (e.g as shown here or here), it would not help much, because the returned WindowsFormsHost would still have been created in a different thread than the main UI thread of your application, and could hence not be added to the application's visual tree.

You should try to split your method into two parts, where creating the report data could be done in a Task, but the UI elements that show the data are created in the UI thread.
